# Convert String date to ISO date format "2019-07-01T03:50:00.000Z" in Java

Tags: java, spring, datetime, time, jodatime

How can  I convert the  date "`Mon Jul 01 08:00:00 IST 2019`" of type string  to ISODate "`2019-07-01T03:00:00.000Z`"?

Comment: For most purposes you should not want to convert a datetime string in one format to another format. Instead inside your program you should keep date and time in a proper date-time object, for example `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`. Only when you need to give out a string, format your date and time into one.